# handbrakecli/ffmpeg command to encode and auto filename(Ubuntu)

Tags: ffmpeg, handbrake, handbrakecli

I have 2 preset .json files(from the GUI version on windows) to convert mkv to mp4.

1. converts to h264 and adds subtitle 1
2. converts to h264

I'm only trying to get no.2 to work at this stage.

`` for i in `*.mkv`; do HandBrakeCLI --preset-import-file HPRESET.json -Z "MYPRESET" --output *.mp4; done ``
no output name

`HandBrakeCLI -i $1 --preset-import-gui HPRESET.json -Z "MYPRESET" --output $1.mp4`

errors on output name

`` for i in `*.mkv`; do HandBrakeCLI --title $i --preset "Very Fast 1080p30" --output *.mp4; done ``

errors on output name AND not valid preset.

`` $ for i in `seq 4`; do HandBrakeCLI --input /dev/dvd --title $i --preset Normal --output NameOfDisc_Title$i.mp4; done ``
copied this from another stackoverflow question, but outputs as 1.mp4 and then 2.mp4 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the filename without extension with something like that:

```
noext=${i%.*}
```

### Example:

```
╰─$ for i in *.mkv; do echo "$i"; noext=${i%.*}; echo "$noext"; done
asdf.mkv
asdf
test.mkv
test
```

Same loop, different notation:

```
for i in *.mkv
do
    #put the commands you want to run after "do" and before "done"
    echo "$i"
    noext=${i%.*}
    echo "$noext"
done
```

Note that the `for` command will search any file in the current directory ending with `.mkv`. For each file it has found, it will save the files name into the variable `$i`, then execute the commands after `do`, then save the next files name into the variable `$i` and execute the commands between `do` and `done`. It will repeat that cycle until every file which has been found is processed.

As I have no experience with handbrake presets, here a solution with `ffmpeg`:

```
for i in *.mkv
do
    #put the commands you want to run after "do" and before "done"
    noext=${i%.*}
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -c:s copy "$noext.mp4"
done
```

Comment: thats but didnt end up helping. it only echos the name, but even trying `for i in noext=${i%.*}; do HandBrakeCLI --input /www/video --preset-import-file HPRESET.json -Z "MYPRESET" --output $noext.mp4; done` or many other variations still wont work

Comment: @Michaelp I am not sure if you understand how a `for` loop works, maybe you should start by learning the [fundamentals of a for loop in linux](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/For_loop).

Comment: your edit works perfectly(for both). thank you so much